# WordPress WYSIWYG editor on demand, responsive

Tags: tinymce

I have created a WYSIWYG editor inside of a metabox, and I have loaded it on demand via javasacript. But the WYSIWYG is not responsive, like the default one is. How can I make it responsive? It sits inside of a table, and the table width is set to 100%. As the rows get smaller the WYSIWYG remains the same size but part of the editor becomes hidden.

I've tried:

```
.mceToolbarTop * {
float:left;
}

.mceToolbarTop select {
width:auto!important;
}

.mceToolbarTop option {
float:none;
}
```

The html is really long, and difficult to format here. Or else i'd paste it.

My container holding the WYSIWYG is 80% wide, and the WYSIWYG styles is set to 100%, so I don't know why its not respecting the styles I have set.

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the page structure. But it's likely that the textarea or a parent of it has a fixed width.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was able to find a fix on a random SO answer from a few months back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code to FORCE the buttons to wrap when the width of the editor hit a certain width, I used this code:

where single-movie-row is the container holding my WYSIWYG

```
.single-movie-row .mceToolbar td {
    display:table-row;
    float: left;
}
.single-movie-row .mceToolbar td:nth-of-type(11){
    clear: left;
}
```